# Root shell is "colored" but not my regular user. Why?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu 18.04 server, if I login with root credential i get "colored" shell. With other regular user not.

Why and how can I get color shell to other regular user ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "colored shell" ?  The prompt? Compare the `$PS1` variables.

Comment: I mean directory color, file different color etc..

Comment: Ah. Check the `alias` command - one of the accounts could have something like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` in one of the startup scripts.

Comment: alias command return null .. nothing... instead root return some strings and "alias ls='ls --color=auto'" ... Where Can I put color=auto ?

Comment: depends on what shell, etc. but `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` could be appropriate.

Comment: Shells have no colour, it is the terminal. What colour are-you/are-you-not seeing? (amend the question).

Comment: You can put it into `~/.bash_aliases` (if bash), however it should already be setup. Is it only one user that it is broken for? You may have a broken config. What shell are you using? What is the output of `echo $0`?